# My suffix is after removal, I express disapproval

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is a happy pet,
>
> My suffix is after removal.
>
> My infix is getting set,
>
> I express disapproval.

Comment: Pursed lips, almost

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> doggone ?

My prefix is a happy pet

> dog

My suffix is after removal

> gone

My infix is getting set

> get ready, get set, go!

I express disapproval

> "doggone it!"

Answer (score 0):

This could be

> **PROTEST**

My prefix is a happy pet,

> **PR** - Prrrr - the sound of a happy pet

My suffix is after removal.

> **TEST** - Something removed during surgery may need to have a test run on it.

My infix is getting set,

> **O** - Almost GO

I express disapproval.

> We protest to show our disapproval of something.